# How can we pass custom parameters in playwright testing framework?

Tags: javascript, playwright

As compared to the selenium grid where it allows the user to pass the custom parameters like test-name, build-name, tags etc..

Is there any possibility where we pass the same custom parameters using playwirght?

Comment: which test runner you are using with playwright it is jest or some thing else?

Comment: I'm using jest runner